# using compress.zlib:// in HHVM

Tags: php, debian, zlib, hhvm

How can I stream zipped XML files with HHVM? (I am on Debian 7 using a prebuild package from hhvm.com)

I am trying:

```
$sourceXml = new \XMLReader();
$sourceXml->open("compress.zlib://$filename");
```

But getting:

> Warning: Unable to open source data

This code works fine using PHP 5.4 but I need to run it with the HipHopVM. And I can't uncompress the files, because they are huge and there are too many of them.

Comment: I have been seeing the same issue. Looks like a fix is coming soon: http://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/842d6fb7dcd6d669b41bf179ec4602793fa38a7a